# Change background color of hyperlinks

Tags: context, backgrounds, links

Is there a way in ConTeXt to **change background color of PDF hyperlinks**?

**Edit**: By hyperlinks, I mean external (via `\useURL`), internal (`\goto`) and footnote links. I can't easily change all those to custom commands; I'm searching for such a `setup`-like command instead. And from [Jairo A. del Rio's answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567719/178125), I know of [text backgrounds](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/TextBackground); but I couldn't figure out how to put that in all those commands or in `\setupinteraction`.

I know one can change text color with `\setupinteraction`: `color` for external links or links to another page, `contrastcolor` for links to same page, being green and red their defaults. I tried using `style` key as below, without success. Following MWE:

```latex
\setupinteraction [state=start,
                   style={backgroundcolor=yellow}]  % relevant line; doesn't work

% code below just for testing
\definepapersize[default][A8,portrait]
\setuppapersize [default]
\useURL[aurl][https://wiki.contextgarden.net][][ConTeXt Garden]
\setupexternalfigures[location={default}]
\starttext
Testing links to same page via a note\footnote{This should create link to same page.},
a figure like \goto{figure~1}[figure1]
and an external link: \from[aurl].

\startplacefigure[title={Figure for testing},reference=figure1]{\externalfigure[cow][width=1\textwidth]}\stopplacefigure
\stoptext
```

generates document below. Note that, as `style` accepts just one command (I guess), it happens to insert "backgroundcolor=yellow" before actual link.

[image: Generated document from MWE above.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PREAMBLE:** [ConTeXt mailing lists](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mailing_Lists) are better places to make questions and answers wrt ConTeXt. Consider joining :)

Your example won't work because AFAIK `style` doesn't accept tables as arguments. A workaround consists of defining a text background, which inherits a lot of settings of `framed` but is able to break across lines and paragraphs, and then apply it to the fourth argument of `useurl`. The only disadvantage is you'll have to manually include `\MyUrl` every time you set a URL.

I'm not sure whether or not you're asking for footnotes too, so just in case...

**EDIT:** Wolfgang Schuster suggested [bars](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/_bar) instead:

```
%Style and color are customizable here
%Suggestion by Wolfgang Schuster
\definebar
[urlbackground]
[color=yellow,
order=background,
continue=yes,
rulethickness=2.8,
offset=1.4]

\setupinteraction
[state=start,
style={\setbar[urlbackground]}]
%
%For highlighting footnote marks
%Comment these two lines if you don't need them
\def\myfootnote#1{\setbar[urlbackground]{\high{#1}}} % Text superscripts
\setupfootnotes[textcommand=\myfootnote] % Highlight in footnote marks
% code below just for testing
\definepapersize[default][A8,portrait]
\setuppapersize [default]
\useURL[aurl] [https://wiki.contextgarden.net] [] [\MyUrl{ConTeXt Garden}]
\starttext
Testing links to same page\footnote{This should create links to same page} and an external link: \from[aurl].
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I'm not able to change all occurrences of `\useURL`: I'm using ConTeXt via Pandoc, which generates a `.tex` file based on a template. I can change all `\setup`s and `\define`s, but not actual commands used in text. (In fact, I can write a Pandoc filter in Lua to do that, but it'd be a little cumbersome.) Is there a way to put `\MyURL` in `before` key of a command that setups links?

Comment: I'm sorry: in fact, my problem doesn't involve only `\useURL`, but also `\goto`: `\useURL` is used by Pandoc to external links, and `\goto` to internal links. I will clarify that in the question. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @JosédeMattosNeto `\setupinteraction [state=start,style={\MyUrl}]` does quite what you need, but sometimes it doesn't work well with line breaks.

Comment: I tried your last suggestion, and you're right: it fails when link needs to break across lines... Almost... Thank you.

Comment: @JosédeMattosNeto See edited answer.

Comment: It's perfect now with bars! Thank you very much, Jairo A. del Rio!

Comment: By the way, second paragraph after edit ("Your example won't...") could be improved: not "defining a edit", but "defining a textbackground", which is the solution before your edit. And thank you for suggesting mailing lists.